# How to pass values from One controller to another Controller in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello In my project I have to pass a welcome message with *username* to the Index Page
Its a MVC3 ASP.Net Razor project

There are two controllers are there; One is Login Controller and the  second one is Home Controller. From Login Controller, I have to pass *UserName* of the Login Person to the view Page.

Login Controller redirect to Another controller called Home Controller .From there I have to pass that value to the view page. That's my issue. I have tried with single controller to view, its working.

I cant use the single controller because Login Controller uses Login Page and Home Controller uses Home Page. Both are separate views.

I have tried Like this, but its not working. Can you suggest a good Method to follow?

Login Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{        
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (DataAccess.DAL.UserIsValid(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home" );
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username or Password");
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Home Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try with Session, like

```
Session["username"] = username;
```

and for recover in the other controller use

```
var username = (string)Session["username"]
```

or in your redirect try with

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Nome", new{ username: username})
```

but the action of your controller must have as argument the (string username) like

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Passing data as parameter to RedirecttoAction doesn't work. The reason for this has been explained in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32174158/5333178

Comment: According to MSDN and to what i made it works https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You could retrieve the currently authenticated username from the `User` instance:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Change the Index() method of Home Controller to this:

   ```
   [HttpPost]

   public ActionResult Index(string username)
   {
        ViewBag.user=username; 
        return View();
   }
   ```
2. Modify the Login Controller :

   ```
   if (DataAccess.DAL.UserIsValid(model.UserName, model.Password))
   {
       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false); 
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home",new { username = model.Username } ); 
       //sending the parameter 'username'value to Index of Home Controller
   }
   ```

Go to the View Page of the Index method of Home Controller and add the following:

```
 <p>User is: @ViewBag.user</p>
```

And you're done. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use TempData. Its data is available in the next request also.

```
// after login
TempData["message"] = "whatever";

// home/index
var message = TempData["message"] as string;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this value is lost if the user refreshes the page.