# Is it possible to RedirectToAction passing data without using parameters in an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my controller of an ASP.NET MVC project, I have a

```
return RedirectToAction("CreatePerson", "Home")
```

This View is a form that creates a person and that works fine.  However, I want to RedirectToAction and pre-fill the form with data collected from a form that creates a User for the system.

How would I pass the data from the CreateUser form in the CreatePerson form?

I know that I could use parameters, but would this really be the best method if most of the time I am calling the CreatePerson view without needing those parameters.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Passing-Data-with-RedirectToAction--in-NET-MVC

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't send data with a `RedirectAction`. That's because you're doing a `301` redirection and that goes back to the client.

So better use `TempData`

Assuming you will have model to `createperson` with following properties:

```
public class CreatePersonData
{
     public string name {get; set;}
     public string address {get; set;}
}
```

Now fill the `model` and store in `TempData`

```
CreatePersonData person=new CreatePersonData();
person.name="SomeName";
person.address="SomeAddress";
TempData["person"]=person;

return RedirectToAction("CreatePerson", "Home")
```

Now while receiving just receive it from `tempdata` and pass the filled `model` to the `view`

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson()
{
    CreatePersonData person=new CreatePersonData()
    var loadPerson= TempData["person"];
    person = loadPerson;
    return View(person);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

As @StephenMuecke made a point of loosing data with `TempData` you might need to use `.Keep` or `.Peek` with TempData to retain the value for future requests

Ex:

with `.Peek`

```
//PEEK value so it is not deleted at the end of the request
var loadPerson= TempData.Peek("person");
```

or with `.Keep`

```
//get value marking it from deletion
var loadPerson = TempData["person"];
//later on decide to keep it
TempData.Keep("person");
```

or as @Stephen said just pass the `id` and select the `user` from **database**

Ex:

```
return RedirectToAction("CreatePerson", "Home", new { ID = User.ID });
```

Now in your `CreatePerson` `ActionResult` just get it from db as below:

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson(int ID)
{
    CreatePersonData person=new CreatePersonData();
    var user=(from u in tbl_user select u where u.ID=ID);
    person.name=user.name;
    person.address=user.address;
    return View(person);
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

You can combine both of the above approaches like storing data in `TempData` and passing the `ID` with `routeValues` and check if `TempData` isn't null then fallback to retrieval of data using `ID` approach.

**Ex:**

```
public class CreatePersonData
{
     public string Id{get; set;}
     public string name {get; set;}
     public string address {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult CreatePerson(int ID)
{
    CreatePersonData person=new CreatePersonData();
    var loadPerson=(CreatePersonData)TempData.Peek("person"); //cast the object from TempData
    if(loadPerson!=null && loadPerson.Id==ID)
    { 
        person=loadPerson;
    }
    else
    {
         var user=(from u in tbl_user select u where u.ID=ID);
         person.name=user.name;
         person.address=user.address;
    }
    return View(person);
}
```

Comment: Can you do this - yes, but should you - no. `TempData` only lasts one redirect so if the user refreshes the browser the data is lost. You also need to cast `loadPerson`. And its a GET method - a user could navigate to it from thier browser history or by just typing it into the address bar causing it to fail (`TempData["person"]` no longer exists or may be a totally different object). At the very least, pass the ID of the object as a route parameter so if the `TempData` object no longer exists or does not match the given ID, the object can be retrieved from the database.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Updated answer.. Correct me if anything wrong.. :)

Comment: Looks better (except you have still not cast the `TempData` object to the type required - but we don't know what the types are anyway :). You can obviously combine both. Pass the ID and `TempData`, then check `TempData` - if its not `null` and its ID matches the parameter, use it, otherwise call the database.

Comment: more about  TempData.http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-in-mvc1

Answer (score 0):

Many Overloads exist for this

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, object routeValues);
```

What you want to do is right click on that Method and View Definition,  you should see many overloads for it

```
// Summary:
    //     Redirects to the specified action using the action name and route values.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   actionName:
    //     The name of the action.
    //
    //   routeValues:
    //     The parameters for a route.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The redirect result object.
```

Answer (score 0):

1- create an object of your model
2- you can use session to pass parameter to your other action,
3- then put the object in a viewbag agg get it in your view